# Opening Specific Webpages after a certain time interval in Django

Tags: django

I cannot find out a way through which I can link webpage in django that can open automatically after a specific tie interval..
Using the javascript function of "window.location" is of no use when the site server is remotely opened as when this script gets called Django Server returns an error of URL not found.
So can anyone help me how to add URLPattern in my urls.py file so that this error can be resolved??

Comment: The window.location call works like entering the website in the browser. Can you post your code so that we can find the mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to get to the solution. I was certainly doing a big blunder in URL Mapping in urls.py file which helped me to get to the desired output.Thank you!